# Efficient integer input / output (with a use case)

Tags: performance, c, io, integer

### The task:

A set of functions used to read/write integers from/to stdin/stdout as efficiently as possible.

### Rationale:

`printf`/`scanf` fail to offer best possible performance. For example, it [is possible](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=problem_stats&problemid=996&category=) to write a solution for UVA problem 10055 "[Hashmat the Brave Warrior](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=996)" that runs in below 0.01 sec, however a straightforward solution with `printf` / `scanf` [typically runs in around 0.02 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44108745/how-to-optimize-printing-out-the-difference-between-the-greater-and-the-lesser-o). Digit by digit input/output of numbers using `getchar_unlocked` and `putchar_unlocked` is the only way I'm aware of to make it run as fast as possible.

### Result:

- Functions `rd*` read integers, and functions `wr*` write integers.
- The next few letters in the function's name describe the type the function operates on, with similar naming conventions to `printf`/`scanf` format specifiers. So for example `rdllu` reads an `unsigned long long int`, while `wrhhi` writes the numerical value of a `signed char`. (It is possible to use a function operating on unsigned integers to read / write a signed integer, this will simply skip checking if the integer is negative).
- In addition, every `rd*` function has a counterpart ending with `eof`, meaning that it checks for EndOfFile and returns `0` in that case. Functions not checking for EOF always return `1`. This is to enable convenient reading a few integers in a loop like `while(rdllueof(&a) && rdllu(&b)) {do_something;}`.
- You might say that these names are cryptic and unreadable. Honestly though, I think they're not much worse than standard library functions like `strncmpy`. And definitely much better than the alternative, that is `read_unsigned_long_long_int_while_checking_for_eof`. If I am to avoid such long names I'm not sure what else can I devise.

### Approach:

Sorry for using macros to generate these functions, that's another point I suppose you might think is wrong. But otherwise I'd have to write 30 repetitive functions, which would violate DRY pretty hard.

### The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fisdigit(int ch)
{
        return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9';
}

#define rdi_funcname_sign_1_eof_1(abbrev) rd##abbrev##ieof
#define rdi_funcname_sign_1_eof_0(abbrev) rd##abbrev##i
#define rdi_funcname_sign_0_eof_1(abbrev) rd##abbrev##ueof
#define rdi_funcname_sign_0_eof_0(abbrev) rd##abbrev##u

#define wri_funcname_sign_1(abbrev) wr##abbrev##i
#define wri_funcname_sign_0(abbrev) wr##abbrev##u

#define rwi_argtype_sign_1(type) unsigned type
#define rwi_argtype_sign_0(type) signed type

#define read_integer(type, abbrev, check_sign, check_eof) \
        int \
        rdi_funcname_sign_##check_sign##_eof_##check_eof(abbrev) \
        (rwi_argtype_sign_##check_sign(type)* n) \
        { \
                *n = 0; \
                int ch; \
                int is_neg = 0; \
                \
                do { \
                        ch = getchar_unlocked(); \
                        if(check_eof) { \
                                if(ch == EOF) \
                                        return 0; \
                        } \
                        if(check_sign) { \
                                if(ch == '-') \
                                        is_neg = 1; \
                        }\
                } while(!fisdigit(ch)); \
                \
                do { \
                        *n *= 10; \
                        *n += ch-'0'; \
                        ch = getchar_unlocked(); \
                } while(fisdigit(ch)); \
                if(check_sign) { \
                        if(is_neg) \
                                *n *= -1; \
                } \
                return 1; \
        }

#define write_integer(type, abbrev, check_sign, max_digits) \
        void \
        wri_funcname_sign_##check_sign(abbrev) \
        (rwi_argtype_sign_##check_sign(type) n) \
        { \
                size_t const buffsiz = \
                        (check_sign ? max_digits+1 : max_digits); \
                char buff[max_digits]; \
                \
                size_t i = 0; \
                if(check_sign) {  \
                        if(n < 0) \
                                buff[i++] = '-'; \
                } \
                while(n != 0) { \
                        buff[i++] = n%10; \
                        n /= 10; \
                } \
                \
                if(i == 0) \
                        putchar_unlocked('0'); \
                else \
                        while(i-- != 0) \
                                putchar_unlocked(buff[i] + '0'); \
                \
                return; \
        }


#define rwi_variations(type, abbrev, max_digits_i, max_digits_u) \
        read_integer(type, abbrev, 1, 1) \
        read_integer(type, abbrev, 1, 0) \
        read_integer(type, abbrev, 0, 1) \
        read_integer(type, abbrev, 0, 0) \
        write_integer(type, abbrev, 1, max_digits_i) \
        write_integer(type, abbrev, 0, max_digits_u)

rwi_variations(long long int, ll, 19, 20)
rwi_variations(long int, l, 10, 10)
rwi_variations(int, , 5, 5)
rwi_variations(short int, h, 5, 5)
rwi_variations(char, hh, 3, 3)

#undef rdi_funcname_sign_1_eof_1
#undef rdi_funcname_sign_0_eof_1
#undef rdi_funcname_sign_1_eof_0
#undef rdi_funcname_sign_0_eof_0
#undef wri_funcname_sign_1
#undef wri_funcname_sign_0
#undef rwi_argtype_sign_1
#undef rwi_argtype_sign_0
#undef rwi_variations
#undef read_integer
#undef write_integer
```

### Restriction:

Must compile with `ANSI C 5.3.0 - GNU C Compiler with options: -lm -lcrypt -O2 -pipe -ansi -DONLINE_JUDGE`

### Use case:

The solution for the aforementioned [UVA Problem 10055: "Hashmat the Brave Warrior"](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=996):

```
void wrc(char c)
{
        putchar_unlocked(c);
}

int main()
{
        unsigned long long int a, b;
        while(rdllueof(&a) && rdllu(&b)) {
                if(a > b)
                        wrllu(a-b);
                else
                        wrllu(b-a);

                wrc('\n');
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I added the `wrc` function just for consistency with the naming convention of `wrllu` et al. I think it's better to print everything with `wr*` rather than print integers with `wr*` and characters with `putchar_unlocked`.

### PS

Any way to optimize this even more?

Comment: Please do not edit after the question has been answered, it invalidates the answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Even when I'm correcting bugs? Oookkkaaaayyy...

Comment: See this help page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Unclear on `write_integer(type, abbrev, 1, max_digits_i) \
        write_integer(type, abbrev, 0, max_digits_u)`.  How does the receiving side separate the 2 integers as would they not be textually concatenated?

Comment: @chux Err it is the responsibility of the caller to separate these two integers, for example to don't do `wrhhu(5); wrhhu(6);` but rather `wrhhu(5); wrc(' '); wrhhu(6)` Not sure why should it be any other way, C++ `iostream` facilities work in a similar way wrt this, http://ideone.com/XwFCnH

Comment: [OK](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165646/efficient-integer-input-output-with-a-use-case?noredirect=1#comment315713_165646) - trying to clarify the overall usage.  Design query: With `read_integer()`, should not the code `ungetc` any non-numeric input so a subsequent input function can consume the character like typical iostreams?  Consider `"123-456"` consumes `"123-"` on the first call  leaving `"456"` for the next call and not `"-456"`.

Comment: @chux My thinking is that this would hamper performance, thereofore colliding with the primary goal of these functions. Most often it would be unnecessary, since anyway, this consumed terminating character is simply a meaningless whitespace. Granted, sometimes it would be necessary. Perhaps I should add another set of variations doing this ungetc, solving the tradeoff between performance and functionality in a manner similar to checking or not checking for eof. This would balloon the overall number of functions to 50...

Comment: @gaazkam Primary goal is correct functionality even when high performance is a high goal.  Without un-getting a non-numeric I suspect  use of these functions would surprise users in too  many corner cases. leading to bugs or nonacceptance of this interesting idea.  Look forward to a new post of your updated solution.  Good luck

Comment: @chux I definitely intend to post an updated version as soon as I have a little time... which will be in a week, sorry :(

Answer (score 3):

You worry about violating DRY, but you've violated a C standard, macros should always be all capitals.

**While I don't recommend it**, the fastest code would be to avoid the use of functions totally and just have the macros. Inline code should always be faster than functions, although on modern computers this is less of an issue.

The `fisdigit()` function can be a macro or just inline

```
do {
    ...
} while(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9');
```

For performance reasons you don't want to call a function.

Check the `ctype.h` file, `isdigit()` may be a macro, in older versions of C (pre **C89** for sure, possible pre **C99** ) all functions provided by `ctype.h` were macros.

**Type Issues**
The variables `a` and `b` in main are declared as unsigned long long, however the functions are expecting pointers to long long. It's also unclear that long long is required since 2^32 is the max value for either `a` or `b`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However: (a) It seems that `-O2` does optimize and inline function calls https://godbolt.org/g/Cyp1ej , so there seems to be no difference between macroifying or manually inlining `fisdigit` and calling `fisdigit` as a function. (b) If I didn't screw the macro code, `rdllu` and `rdllueof` should be expecting ptrs to `unsigned long long` rather than `long long` I have a vague feeling that i is permitted to read an integer through a pointer of a different singedness anyway, though I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: (c) `long long` is required, this is a peculiarity of this task. The problem is that max value for either `a` or `b` is 2^32, while the max value of `unsigned long` is 2^32-1 , so we'd have an overflow in the corner case.

Comment: @gaazkam My compiler is giving me warnings about unsigned versus signed in the read functions. My comment about removing functions applied to all of the functions, both read and write.

Comment: One final note: The real reason I chose to redefine `isdigit`: I thought I'd sooner or later expand this "library" to doubles, fixed-point, strings, etc, and that's where locale issues would kick in if I kept using `ctype.h` functions, and I wanted to avoid this for the sake of simplicity and to avoid any overhead, so I thought for consistency I'd redefine everything in the first place.

Comment: Oh my, I really did screw up this signedness, thank You for noticing this. I fixed this error, as well as one more silly error that could result in a buffer overflow, here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/165646/revisions Have an upvote and thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for noting the need of inlining all `rd*` and `wr*` functions. It would seem that to achieve max performance they don't have to be explicitly macroified: instead we can get the same effect if we add the `__inline__` keyword: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Inline.html And it does seem to be working: https://godbolt.org/g/586vSx

Comment: gaazkam is absolutely correct. There is no reason to use macros for performance in modern C. With optimizations enabled and the function definition visible, all compilers will inline the code if that is a performance win. Better yet, they will *not* inline the code if that causes a performance degradation, which is a guarantee that you don't get with macros. If you want to help out the optimizer in making  a decision, you can use the `inline` keyword, but that's really not necessary. You only need macros if you actually need compile-time tokenization.

Comment: Also, macros being in all caps is not a "C standard". At best, its a convention. I personally follow this convention, and it's reasonable to suggest that someone follow this convention in a code review, but let's not make it out to be more than it is—pure style.

Comment: @CodyGray Unfortunately, in this case the `__inline__` keyword seems necessary, since the compiler fails to inline these functions without it.

Comment: "violated a C standard, macros should always be all capitals."  The C spec doe not specify this - it is not a violation.  The C spec contains many counter examples: `PRId32`, `SCNxMAX`, potentially `getc`, `va_start`,  `complex`, `bool`, sample codes `#define mkstr(a) # a`, `#define f(a) a*g`, `#define abs(x) _BUILTIN_abs(x)`, and many others.  Not using lower case letters for macros is a convention/style, not a spec.  Style concerns are best followed per the group's coding standards which may or may not  exclude using lower case in user-code macros.

Answer (score 2):

1. Bug: Below fails to print digits when `n<0`

   ```
   buff[i++] = n%10; ... putchar_unlocked(buff[i] + '0')
   ```
2. `if(i == 0)` not needed, just use a `do {} while`

   ```
         do {
            buff[i++] = n%10;
         } while (n /= 10);
   ```
3. Bug.  Wrong array size

   ```
   size_t const buffsiz = (check_sign ? max_digits+1 : max_digits); \
   // char buff[max_digits];
   char buff[buffsiz];
   ```
4. Why stingy on buffer size?  Could simply use +1 always

   ```
   size_t const buffsiz = max_digits+1;
   char buff[buffsiz];
   ```
5. Bug `buff[i++] = '-' ... putchar_unlocked(buff[i] + '0');` will not print a `'-'`.

Comment: 1) You're right, thank you! 2) Indeed a neater construct, thank you! 3) You're right... I figured it out myself some time before, and even edited the question to remove this bug, but this edit got reverted... 4) Because why not? It's dispatched compile-time, so adds not runtime overhead! 5) Aaand you're right again. Have an upvote, thank you!